# Как написать функцию для кнопки в React Js

Tags: html, reactjs

Для кнопки с HTML документа надо написать функцию для JS React которая считывает информацию с input type="text" и записывает в такую переменную.

```
var PLACES = [
{ name: "New York", zip: "10157" },
{ name: "Rome", zip: "00123" }
];
```

Comment: Функцию писать так же, как и любую другую. Имя, параметры... вешаете обработчик на `onClick`, внутри функции делаете что нужно. Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен, откуда берутся значения `name` и `zip`... если вам нужно пример того, как достать значение из `input` и сохранить - могу написать.

Comment: @Denis Bubnov Если можете напишите буду благодарен.Мне нужно чтобы оно сохранялось в эту переменную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий вариант:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);
  const [newPlace, setNewPlace] = useState({});

  const handleCLick = () => {
    setPlaces([ ...places, newPlace]);
    setNewPlace({ name: '', zip: '' });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          placeholder="Enter place name"
          value={newPlace.name}
          onChange={e => setNewPlace({ ...newPlace, name: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input 
          placeholder="Enter place zip"
          value={newPlace.zip}
          onChange={e => setNewPlace({ ...newPlace, zip: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleCLick}>Create Place</button>
      <h2>Places:</h2>
      {
        places.map(
          ({ name, zip }) => (
            <div key={name}>
              name: <b>{name}</b>, zip: <b>{zip}</b>
            </div>
          )
        )
      }
    </>
  )  
};

export default App;
```

Версия реакта должна быть не ниже 16.8.0

https://codepen.io/smolinpavel/full/KYvqqZ

Comment: @AndrewUngurian это ошибка говорит о том, что вы определили переменную App, но нигде её не используете

Comment: Простите а можно куда-то сбросить вам файл с кодом чтобы вы посмотрели на весь код?

Comment: @AndrewUngurian email: isingwithaz@gmail.com, skype: pashaflat53